# How install sdkman for gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, sdkman

I tried to install gradle but first I need to install sdkman. Official instruction does not work:

curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash

I don't like where this is going already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# host get.sdkman.io
get.sdkman.io has address 159.89.187.78
```

IP 159.89.187.78 is in Roscomnadzor blacklist.
You can check it:

https://blocklist.rkn.gov.ru/